# Prerequisite knowledge

Tags: wallets, dapp-development, myetherwallet

I am interested working with MyEtherWallet as a programmer. For my first project I would like to remove the parts which would not be used on an air-gapped computer. I am already familiar with HTML, JavaScript, CSS, Geth, Web3 and Solidity. The github page tells what one needs to know in order to compile and run the code.

Would someone please tell me what other languages, libraries, frameworks, and technologies I will need to study in order to make useful changes and additions to the MyEtherWallet open source project? Also please tell me if you know about any good learning resources which are particularly applicable to working with MyEtherWallet source code.
Thanks for the help

Update: Some kind person on another forum told me that by looking in the package json file I can tell Angular 1 is used. I am off to YouTube to find out how to work with Angular 1 then I will take a crack at understanding how MyEtherWallet works.

Any other advice of that nature would be much appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Maybe, it would be interesting to learn Go language, as they are quite related to geth.

You have here the web: 
[GoLang](https://golang.org/)

And here the Official golang implementation of the Ethereum protocol:
[Ethereum Go](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum)

Of Course, you need to learn Solidity for program the smart contracts inside the blockchain: [Solidity](https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/develop/)

If you want to program an app, you can see other examples [here](https://dapps.ethercasts.com/), some DApps have code open and is nice source for learn some tips about contracts and structures of them.

And related with frameworks and technologies, perhaps these three are useful to you:

- [Metamask](https://metamask.io/)
- [Truffle](https://github.com/trufflesuite/truffle)
- [Meteor.js](https://www.meteor.com/)

Comment: Thanks for your kind response, but I need to work specifically with MyEtherWallet source code because it is already pretty close to what I need. I see it is built with the Angular framework, but which one? Angular 1 or Angular 4. I understand they are quite different and incompatible. If it's Angular 2 or 4, is TypeScript involved? JQuery is also mentioned in the github md file. Do I need to study that? Basically I need to understand how MyEtherWallet source code works and how to work with it. So I need an answer from someone who has worked with MyEtherWallet source code.

Comment: Oh well, for it doesn't exist a lot of information about it. I've been looking at the git and doesn't have a good explanation. maybe you can contact with them...